# please hepl i am not able to find whats wrong app when any button pressed closes

Tags: android

```
package my.medai;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MediaplayerexampleActivity extends Activity {
    Button play, pause;
    MediaPlayer mp;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alone);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();

            }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {mp.stop();}});

    }
}
```

i am new to prgraming.this is java xml just contains two buttons that are produced by drag and drop 
the application closes unexpectedly when any or two button is pressed

Answer (score 3):

Most likely `mp` is null because it's not assigned, causing a NullPointerException. This line:

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alone);
```

should rather look like

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alone);
```

*Since `MediaPlayer.create()` can return null when the creation of the player fails, you should add some additional null checks too, just to be safe*

Comment: thanx alextsc and imran it worked

Answer (score 1):

use

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mp =MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alone);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alone);
```

Comment: if it's working then u can accept it as answer for others help who is looking for same problem.thanks friend